# Why jeditable WYSIWYG plugin behave differently in different web-browsers?

Tags: browser, html, compatibility, jquery, wysiwyg

Normally when we type a sentence in an wysiwyg editor and if we need one in next line we use to press the enter key and it will automatically insert a `<br>` tag. But when we use the jeditable WYSIWYG editor and do this it is inserting `<p></p>` tags instead of `<br>` in internet explorer and  tag in chrome.

But it is inserting `<br>` tag in Mozilla (which is the right one).
On IE is providing `<p>` tag instead of `<br>` when pressing enter key in jeditable WYSIWYG editor.

I am using Jeditable as inline editor (see [demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.html)). When using the wysiwyg editor and when I enter my sentence to the next line Firefox is showing the output using `</br>` tag which is the right one.

But chrome and internet explorer is showing different output.

For example:

The original output should be `Lorem Ipsum<br>is simply dummy`  which is showing correctly in Firefox.

But in Internet Explorer the output is `<p>Lorem Ipsum</p><p>is simply dummy</p>`
and in Chrome it is `<div>Lorem Ipsum</div><div>is simply dummy</div>`

How would I make this the same for all the browsers like Firefox is showing?

Comment: Please anyone answer my question. This is really urgent

Comment: Try upgrade your [jWYSIWYG](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg/) plugin as suggested [here](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/issues/143), it's old on the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.html) is using very old version of [jWYSIWYG](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg) plugin (as suggested [here](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/issues/143#issuecomment-80399457)), therefore you should use the upgraded  code.

This was happening because when the editor is initialized and no content is load from textarea,
it put an `<br>`.

Here is the commit fix that you're probably looking for:

[Explanation of brIE-option in README and some code refactoring for the same functionality](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg/commit/4ba2b593b484e1150aa2783bef3994b89b7a6f38) authored by stianlik.

> The ENTER key will no longer reset the style to "Paragraph", but continue writing "Header 1" until users explicitly choose "Paragraph" in the toolbar.

You may use `brIE` option to control this behaviour. Check the [README](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg/blob/master/README.rst) for more details.

Related:

- [Issue 15: adds unwanted `<br>` tags](https://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/issues/detail?id=15) at Google Code
- [#143: editor specific browser-compability issue](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/issues/143) at GitHub